# Problam with ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a panel which contains tables with Textboxes and Buttons (OK, Cancel). When I click "OK" Button, data gets updated (already working) and after that I want the **panel to be disappeared** and **Gridview must be refreshed**.

I already did that in another application, but now I don't know why it doesn't work.

```
     <asp:Panel ID="PanelAjouEnfants" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Prénom :
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_prenomenfant" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Date Naissance :
                            <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender_DateDemande_1" runat="server"
                                TargetControlID="TextBox_dnenfant" DaysModeTitleFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" TodaysDateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_dnenfant" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Scolarise :
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_scol" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Activités :
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_activite" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnValiderAjoutEnfant" runat="server" Text="OK" OnClick="btnValiderAjoutEnfant_Click"
                                CssClass="btn" />
                        </td>
                        <td align="right">
                            <asp:Button ID="B_quitter" runat="server" Text="CANCEL" CssClass="btn" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </asp:Panel>
            <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtenderAjouterEnfants" runat="server"
                TargetControlID="HyperLink1" PopupControlID="PanelAjouEnfants" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
                DropShadow="true" CancelControlID="B_quitter" />
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
```

This my code to validate data:

```
protected void btnValiderAjoutEnfant_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            c.cmd = c.cn.CreateCommand();
            c.cmd.CommandText = "insert into Enfants (Prenom , DateNaissance , Scolarise,Activite, PPR)  values ('" + TextBox_prenomenfant.Text + "','" + TextBox_dnenfant.Text + "','" + TextBox_scol.Text + "','" + TextBox_activite.Text + "'," + Session["Code"] + ")";
            if (c.cn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                c.cn.Open();
            }
            c.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            gv_enfant.DataBind();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert ('Erreur d'ajout!')</script>");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (c.cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                c.cn.Close();
            }

            TextBox_prenomenfant.Text = "";
            TextBox_dnenfant.Text = "";
            TextBox_scol.Text = "";
            TextBox_activite.Text = "";

        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete. btw to hide panel you just have to use PanelAjouEnfants.Visible = false

Comment: ;'Drop Table etc... --

Answer (score 0):

i know where was the the problème , i had :

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>
................
 <ContentTemplate/>
 <asp:UpdatePanel/>
```

and when i removed it , IT  WORKED  , but i don't want to remove it